# How to call a sub script from the main script on a remote server

Tags: powershell

HI i am having problem in calling a sub script from the main script using powershell on a remote server
I have the main script which is call 1.ps1
the other script is called 2.ps1

Here are the scripts

```
1.ps1 contains this code &("C:\Users\test\Desktop\remotely run scripts\2.ps1")
2.ps1 contains this code new-item -type file c:\itworksagain.txt
```

I am running the command as follows:

```
invoke-command -computer "remoteServer" -filepath "C:\Users\test\Desktop\remotely run scripts\1.ps1"
```

I am getting an error

```
The term 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\remotely run scripts\2.ps1 is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, ...
```

Comment: That would work if the script was located on your own machine. If it is located on another computer you should try: `invoke-command { powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\remotely run scripts\2.ps1' } -computername remoteServer`

Comment: no i am getting the error because the files are on my machine.

Comment: both of the files are located on my local machine. the sub script is the one which is not getting executed for some reason

Comment: Just think about it. You run the first script which works fine. This script is now running on a remote machine. Let's call this machine rm01. In this script you are referencing script 2 with a full path. So the script (running on rm01) looks for the script at the given path, but finds nothing. Why? Because it's not there. It's on your local machine, but the script running on rm01 have no knowledge of this.

Answer (score 0):

I should have noticed this before. You have the following in the script

```
&("C:\Users\test\Desktop\remotely run scripts\2.ps1")
```

The brackets in that line are telling PowerShell to run a subexpression called `"C:\Users\test\Desktop\remotely run scripts\2.ps1"` which is not a cmdlet, exe.... etc.
I think your issue might be addressed if you change the line to the following.

```
& "C:\Users\test\Desktop\remotely run scripts\2.ps1"
```

**Update from comments**

Your first script calls the second. The `invoke` command runs the first on the remote server. The script executing on the remote server calls the second script. The call is origination on the remote server so the call is relative to that server. It is looking for `2.ps1` on the remote server. You need to move that script to a central location and then call it from your first with a UNC path which powershell supports. For testing you can move `2.ps1` to the remote server and it should work.

Comment: No luck. i modified the first script to  & "C:\Users\test\Desktop\remotely run scripts\2.ps1" but getting the same error

Comment: This script is on the __local__ computer and it is a valid path? This should work. I will try and reproduce this.

Comment: both script are on my local machine. the second script is the one which tries to create a file on remote server but its not working as expected

Comment: I wonder if the second script needs to be on the remote server. Since it is being called from the script that is executed remotely. All paths must be relative to it. Can you try moving the script to the remote server to test.

Comment: If i run second script 2.ps1 on its own with the above command than it does creates the file. But not sure when i call 2.ps1 from 1.ps1 why it does not get executed and creates a file on remote server

Comment: Because you are calling it from the script you are executing on the remote server. Once it is run remotely is has no connection back to your local computer. Again, I think it is because you are calling a second script inside your first. Leave your scripts the same. Just put the second one on the remote server using the same path. I bet it would work then.

Comment: the goal which we are trying to achieve is to have scripts on our local machine which we can run on remote server rather than loggin into remote server and than running a scrip there on pasting a script first on the remote server and than running from our local machine. I am sure there must be a way to run scripts on a remote server from our local machine

Comment: The first script is being run remotely. The issue is with the second one. If you have to have this second run as a script then put it in a central location and call it using its UNC path.